# Why is PageSpeed Insights summarizing the page speed/field data as slow?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

I see the two values of FCP and DCL, but then above them, the page says this is "Slow". How is that determined?

Comment: FYI, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376575/a-surge-of-comments-complaints-in-pagespeed-insights

Comment: While I'm not a fan of the answer here, is the *question* really unclear? I have not used PageSpeed Insights, and will not vote to reopen since I am not qualified to judge. However, I *suspect* that anyone who had used the tool would know where in the UI the information referred to in this question is shown, and thus would understand the question being asked and find it perfectly clear. I fear that the close voters have not even used the tool, don't have the knowledge to evaluate whether the question is clear, and have just reflexively closevoted after seeing the Meta question linked above.

Comment: @MarkAmery It could be argued that the question is a bit vague, but most important, it has nothing to do with programming. There is no code, not even a concept around programming, at the very least it falls off-topic this forum because of that, more than as "unclear".

Comment: @Alejandro How is it not to do with programming? PageSpeed, as I understand it, is a tool for optimising webpage load times. Is such a tool not of use *only* to web developers? And does it not therefore fall under the [software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) class of questions that are on-topic here, just as clearly as a question about, say, configuring an IDE does?

Comment: I think based on date of question...it had to do with the update the tool that suddenly moved the Field Data and Ranking based off of it from "fast" to "slow" for many major websites.

Answer (score 4):

An overall label is calculated from the field metric values of FCP and FID

- **Fast**: If both FCP and FID are Fast.
- **Slow**: If either FCP or FID is Slow, or if both are Slow.
- **Average**: All other cases.

Comment: Yikes, really? If I'm inferring what happened here correctly, you decided seed a new tag for your employer with an answer straight up copied and pasted from [your own docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about), without attribution, and complete with an English error (now fixed by an editor) from the original? I'd be embarrassed to have my name in this in your place, honestly. Seeding the tag is not inherently problematic, but you could've crafted a better seed Q&A than this.

Comment: One reason OP likely asked why slow, is before mid Nov. the field data used FCP and DCL, showing the median values — fast Page Speed required a median (50th percentile) FCP + DCL value in the top-third of pages in the CrUX report.

Now FCP shows 90th-percentile and FID the 95th-percentile in the Page Speed Overviews. WSJ's mobile homepage saw a drop from fast to slow, as did The Guardian's and WaPo.

Comment: @paul-irish https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658159/why-does-the-page-speed-insights-v5-api-label-google-com-and-other-heavily-traff Any answer to this?